# Node.js net socket doesn't close the socket connection

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to write a typical Node.js server and faced the problem, that client (or server) doesn't really close the socket connection and server doesn't respond on the following connections.

Here is my server.js:

```
const net = require('net');
const serverAddress = '127.0.0.1'; // Replace with the actual server address
const serverPort = 3000; // Replace with the actual server port

const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        console.log('Received request: ', data.toString())
        socket.write('Hi, this is server response');
    });
    socket.on('close', () => {
        socket.end();
        socket.destroy();
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
    socket.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Connection end');
        socket.end();
    });
    socket.on('error', error => {
        console.error('Socket error:', error);
    });
});

server.listen(serverPort, serverAddress, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${serverAddress}:${serverPort}`);
});
```

Here is my client.js:

```
const net = require('net');
const serverAddress = '127.0.0.1'; // Replace with the actual server address
const serverPort = 3000; // Replace with the actual server port

const client = net.createConnection(serverPort, serverAddress, () => {
    console.log('Connected to the server');
    let msg = 'First request';
    client.write(msg);
    console.log("Sent2 to server:", msg)

    client.on('data',  data => {
        console.log('Server response:', data.toString());
        client.end();
    });
    client.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
    client.on('end', async () => {
        console.log('Connection end');
        setTimeout(runSecondConnection, 3000);
    });
});

function runSecondConnection() {
    let client2 = net.createConnection(serverPort, serverAddress, () => {
        console.log('Connected2 to the server');
        let msg = 'Second request';
        client.write(msg);
        console.log("Sent2 to server:", msg)
    })

    client2.on('data', data => {
        console.log('Server2 response:', data.toString());
        client.end();
    });
    client2.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection2 closed');
    });
    client2.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Connection2 end');
    });

}
```

What I get:

```
server:
Received request:  First request
Connection end
Connection closed

client:
Connected to the server
Sent2 to server: First request
Server response: Hi, this is server response
Connection end
Connection closed
Connected2 to the server
Sent2 to server: Second request
```

Client hangs after sending Second request, server does not enter to the `socket.on('data' ...)` listener.

What I expect to get:

```
server:
Received request:  First request
Connection end
Connection closed
Received request:  Second request
Connection end
Connection closed

client:
Connected to the server
Sent2 to server: First request
Server response: Hi, this is server response
Connection end
Connection closed
Connected2 to the server
Sent2 to server: Second request
Server response: Hi, this is server response
Connection end
Connection closed
```

I tried to do socket.end(), socket.destroy() at a client side - no effect.

Also, I noticed, when client is hanging after second request, if I terminate client script, server prints error and one more time prints "Connection closed":

```
Server listening on 127.0.0.1:3000
Received request:  First request
Connection end
Connection closed
Socket error: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:220:20) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
Connection closed
```

Why it is "Connection closed" message after error?
There are 2 connections?
Or  first Connection closed wasn't a really closing?

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code.

Firstly, if you add `console.log('connection')` at the very start of the `createServer` callback then you will be able to see that is called every time your client is connected.

Secondly, you don't need to close connection as `socket.end()` (and `socket.destroy()`) on server side. It's done from client side on disconnect.

And lastly. You do not see an expected output because on the second connection you do not send any data. You are trying to send data to your first connection: `client.write(msg)` instead of `client2.write(msg)`

#### A fixed code

From `server.js`:

```js
const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    socket.on('data', data => {
        console.log('Received request: ', data.toString())
        socket.write('Hi, this is server response');
    });
    socket.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
    socket.on('error', error => {
        console.error('Socket error:', error);
    });
});

server.listen(serverPort, serverAddress, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on ${serverAddress}:${serverPort}`);
});
```

From `client.js`:

```js
function runSecondConnection() {
    let client2 = net.createConnection(serverPort, serverAddress, () => {
        console.log('Connected2 to the server');
        let msg = 'Second request';
        client2.write(msg);
        console.log("Sent2 to server:", msg)
    })

    client2.on('data', data => {
        console.log('Server2 response:', data.toString());
        client.end();
    });
    client2.on('close', () => {
        console.log('Connection2 closed');
    });
    client2.on('end', () => {
        console.log('Connection2 end');
    });
    client2.on('error', error => {
        console.error('Socket2 error:', error);
    });
}
```

Hope this helps!